# Desktop for multiple remote sessions on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, remote-desktop, python, multiuser

I am looking to buy a desktop PC for my company, fast enough that multiple users (4 at a time, at most) can login over network and have decent a development experience. I am looking for some advice on an overall setup.

Programming will be Python 90% of the time, with some JS thrown in. Part of the load will be machine learning, so we will be using a discrete GPU for that (only one neural network application running at the time).

We are not worried about networking, as most connections will happen in-house over ethernet. But perhaps we should?

For specs (and I know shopping recommendations are prohibited here, so let's keep it non-specific) we are looking at

8 cores of consumer grade CPU (or is 12+ really needed?)
32 GB of ram
Fast m2 SSD, 1tb, for main load
Slower HDDs for inactive repos and such.
Mid to High-end ML GPU

For OS, We are looking at Ubuntu, as it seems that it is possible to have multiple full sessions over SSH? I know that Windows server would allow it with RDP, but we like Linux for development.

Is such a setup feasible?
I am mostly concerned with core count and OS.